# Storing unique elements in vector and counting number of duplicates

Tags: java, vector

I have a vector of words but I would like to re-arrange (either in the same vector or in to a new one) the words alphabetically and keep track of how many times each word appears in a text.
Here's how I store the words into the vector:

```
Vector<String> elements = new Vector<String>();

    int i = 0;

    // read infile line by line
    while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null)
    {

        String word;

        StringTokenizer linesplit = new StringTokenizer(line, " ,.-");
        while (linesplit.hasMoreElements()){
            word = linesplit.nextElement().toString() ;

            elements.add(i,(word));
            i++;
        }  
    }
```

To keep track of how many times each word appears I would like to use a counter:

```
public class Entry // implements Comparable<Entry>
    {
   private String word;
   private int counter;
    }
```

How could I check if a word occurs more than once in the current vector and rearrange the unique words alphabetically?

Comment: And What problem you are Facing?

Comment: (1) Why are you using a `Vector` instead of a `List`? `List` has been preferred since Java 1.2. (2) I recommend using Guava's `Multiset`, which is basically a `Map<E, Integer>` that keeps track of how many times an item has been inserted.

Comment: I am not sure how I should proceed. How could check if a word is occurring more than once in the current vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the `Vector` by using `Collections.sort(vector)`.

For storing the number of occurrences for each token, I would suggest using a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, as it has constant access time and you can check easily, if a value is already stored in it using `map.containsKey()`. Then you simply iterate over the vector and count the occurrences of every token.

Answer (score 0):

@Warload has a good idea, but if  you use a `SortedMap<String, Integer>`, then you will be able to accomplish both of your objectives at the same time (sort and count occurrences).

It could look something like this

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
// read infile line by line
while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null)
{

    String word;

    StringTokenizer linesplit = new StringTokenizer(line, " ,.-");
    while (linesplit.hasMoreElements()){
        word = linesplit.nextElement().toString() ;

        if (map.containsValue(word)) {
            int i = map.get(word);
            map.put(word, ++i);
        }
        else {
            map.put(word, 1);
        }
    }  
}


//some time later
Set<String> words = map.keySet();
Collection<Integer> counts = map.values();
```